# How to use raw_input() with while-loop

Tags: python, while-loop, raw-input

Just trying to write a program that will take the users input and add it to the list 'numbers':

```
print "Going to test my knowledge here"
print "Enter a number between 1 and 20:"

i = raw_input('>> ')
numbers = []

while 1 <= i <= 20 :
    print "Ok adding %d to numbers set: " % i 
    numbers.append(i)

    print "Okay the numbers set is now: " , numbers
```

However when I execute the program it only runs to raw_input()

```
Going to test my knowledge here
Enter a number between 1 and 20:
>>> 4
```

Is there some fundamental rule I'm missing here??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string not an integer:

So,

```
>>> 1 <= "4" <= 20
False
```

Use `int()`:

```
i = int(raw_input('>> '))
```

Use just `if`, if you're only taking a single input from user:

```
if 1 <= i <= 20 :
    print "Ok adding %d to numbers set: " % i 
    numbers.append(i)

    print "Okay the numbers set is now: " , numbers
```

Use `while` for multiple inputs:

```
i = int(raw_input('>> '))
numbers = []

while 1 <= i <= 20 :
    print "Ok adding %d to numbers set: " % i 
    numbers.append(i)
    i = int(raw_input('>> '))                   #asks for input again
print "Okay the numbers set is now: " , numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to Ashwini's answer, you will find that raw_input will only run once. If you want to keep prompting the user, put the raw_input inside the while loop:

```
print "Going to test my knowledge here"
print "Enter a number between 1 and 20:"

numbers = []
i = 1
while 1 <= i <= 20 :
    i = int(raw_input('>> '))
    print "Ok adding %d to numbers set: " % i 
    numbers.append(i)

    print "Okay the numbers set is now: " , numbers
```